# Generate a Population in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to generate a population in R for 1000 customers that can fall into a value bucket from 10 to 1000. Customers fall into the buckets in an interval of 10. For example, Cust A can fall into the value bucket 10,20,30....1000. They are mutually exclusive so they can only fall into one bucket in a given scenario. I want a population list that contains all possible scenarios for the 1000 customers. Is this possible at all? as the permutations are rather massive. Appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible and seems simple.

```
set.seed(2317)    # make the results reproducible
bucket <- seq.int(10L, 1000L, by = 10L)
sample(bucket, 1000, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

N=100 : 100 number of buckets
1000 customers

To generate one possible permutation use sample :

```
sample(100,1000,replace=T)
```

To generate 100 possible permutations use replicate

```
replicate(n=100,sample(100,1000,replace=T))
```

You can use gtools package to generate all possible permutations

```
library(gtools)
r <- permutations(100,1000,repeats.allowed=T)
```

But the result matrix will be huge ...

Example with 4 customers and 2 buckets :

```
permutations(2,4,repeats.allowed = T)

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    2
 [3,]    1    1    2    1
 [4,]    1    1    2    2
 [5,]    1    2    1    1
 [6,]    1    2    1    2
 [7,]    1    2    2    1
 [8,]    1    2    2    2
 [9,]    2    1    1    1
[10,]    2    1    1    2
[11,]    2    1    2    1
[12,]    2    1    2    2
[13,]    2    2    1    1
[14,]    2    2    1    2
[15,]    2    2    2    1
[16,]    2    2    2    2
```